# Spring MVC Apache Oltu and Salesforce Integration examples OAUTH_APPROVAL_ERROR_GENERIC : An unexpected error has occured during authentication

Tags: java, salesforce, oltu

I am extending the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530725/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-411-for-url-https-lo

I am developing Spring MVC + Apache Oltu + Salesforce Integration example. In this example, I have created connected App in the Salesforce as shown below:

In this example I am using below:

- ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
- AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize";

What will be the OAuthBearerClientRequest Request ? Like for Github I had used `https://api.github.com/user`. What will be the URL for the salesforce ?

This is getting called from my code:

> https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?scope=full&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapache-oltu%2Fsalesforce%2Fredirect&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPJZPIzGJ5UZDqJOJY.3R6RBM8sJAF8PyTtdTE.DDBnScvPEbcbUmaZ1HQjYItOLpnjY4JHL

but nothing is coming in Authorization.

For ex: **OAuthBearerClientRequest** for

- Linkedin - `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=`
- Facebook - `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`
- Github- `https://api.github.com/user`

**What is for the salesforce ?**

This URL also dont have info what I want: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_using_a_SAML_Bearer_Assertion.

[image]

[image]

The  error which I see:

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

[image]

The issue mention here: **https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLTU-210**

Comment: I'd like to suggest you check out these docs: [Setting Up OAuth 2.0 in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm), [Using OAuth to Authorize External Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications), [Creation a Connected App in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=0).

Comment: @Hleb - It doesn't works for me. I have already raised the separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530725/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-411-for-url-https-lo, but still no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I only got the below details, still looking to make it working**

Understanding OAuth Endpoints
**OAuth endpoints** are the URLs you use to make OAuth authentication requests to Salesforce.

You need to use the correct Salesforce **OAuth** endpoint when issuing authentication requests in your application. The primary OAuth endpoints are:

- **For authorization:** https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
- **For token requests:** https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
- **For revoking OAuth tokens:** https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke

All endpoints require secure HTTP (HTTPS). Each OAuth flow defines which endpoints you need to use and what request data you need to provide.
If you’re verifying authentication on a sandbox organization, use “test.salesforce.com” instead of “login.salesforce.com” in all the OAuth endpoints listed above.

When I spent all 2 weeks, I got the below details as a part of URL:

> http://localhost:8080/apache-oltu/salesforce/redirect#access_token=00D7F0000001I8v%21ARgAQH3Ezr9dXMN2oOwedXsecQOJnNz7fzd8J0b1rv_WGJMLdjntGejARCflNHezO3Jx2EzQ3NCXU5N.9kd3XfIYJsoHuaxo&refresh_token=5Aep8613hy0tHCYdhxJMolioLtSyVWkdY.qjUQIKBDHpKUfFk5dQNWdtRroZqaoeSCMWjemMlechS_MfTRBEYRs&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fap5.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D7F0000001I8vUAE%2F0057F000000l2bgQAA&issued_at=1508009229818&signature=cxOV7F68pvAfoeLZUw1hmZDEx1JKcnFWfpN8dutFPvo%3D&scope=api+web+full+refresh_token&token_type=Bearer

I was able to solve the problems and now I am getting the authorizationCode also which again fetches the `access_token` and `refresh_token` etc.

```
{  
   "access_token":"00D7F0000001I8v!ARgAQDvQR1L4XtPVlSzgBQWwN7vi6an6wp2yVa2E.QeCuJFDmWfjU8UKJnZCY0hNHcISEj4u7aHTzTXKPrZwFO7e_2PjilYY",
   "refresh_token":"5Aep8613hy0tHCYdhxJMolioLtSyVWkdY.qjUQIKBDHpKUfFk7DxakBkr.fqMfwxgDn5GuOHbU8EWoeGkNma4kJ",
   "signature":"KggDhRHjf3/wmU85Cuz5HPriXpvZ7+9nyVMlwFWoizE=",
   "scope":"refresh_token api full",
   "id_token":"eyJraWQiOiIyMTAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdF9oYXNoIjoiYmdveG9KR0k4S1BGa1FvVlU1WlNJUSIsInN1YiI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4uc2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20vaWQvMDBEN0YwMDAwMDAxSTh2VUFFLzAwNTdGMDAwMDAwbDJiZ1FBQSIsImF1ZCI6IjNNVkc5ZDguLnouaERjUEpaUEl6R0o1VVpEckw3Ykp0aEFRX3YwWUN4ekVlRzExSEkxWXdLTmZ2YVlmRHkwbXNKNmF6RTNFQ01COEVHc0YzTlJ0SjAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA4MDExNDA5LCJpYXQiOjE1MDgwMTEyODl9.gvzr9Eq5QpYmG3s8daf55ey9GP9O2SvBN_3LpmlDB334pS6cLzHZrq6Z-zH6mXmgNAD7OEyVhPVLlsm5Ln2iOPC3AtfFhadyGNHrtbwxG9GtaiCoTwsBQ7dtyx5fytZBQnDrKJ6EoshduJkRDbC9GzuBVjGU0dAluqiC8A_BoX4DJcbCetXwk4bS1MTaf7IJNYceZhsIbgaq1y7CBIwYtlJHLURbrct6hkPFQc65zPAZB6_SZD0uifFRptp52VEelJ0GKC03PvzAgPw2ofaoWkdq5f7pdAZQRpPUDCKcplB3whc4vk0fk5uMacDnJBNNRkds3SjKvx3X0Qg0pE0xm5ISac20WhEYzeDVtqmBeqqVes0ZFIC5t3hewWmrLicCAedaAWuKK5LnpKdhYoClw8Hmtt5y_ewf34TbSuzc6mQ9O6fMNs4nDBr5_20LuPC6Z5rPXb-GKNONAySa8rcLAB4hcRimWBLVMhrKFIcLc2WLYd1OvqgnoKc6gMh76_Ibha0R8veORbusgd9AYJoQEsPed5-LzFrczP0DX-PHD9NGOsT5b2t9daxy8sZ3t_vfo__6GCYG_Lq-Ee0JOEWaemHp6P6a8OTSufQkXiiYdAwe2iSHi1mF457mZhGR9f_IJzUFXzHF8lY8q6LGZI2uLOfFJX4qYFt3Cj6RXbIP4hQ",
   "instance_url":"https://ap5.salesforce.com",
   "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D7F0000001I8vUAE/0057F000000l2bgQAA",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "issued_at":"1508011289104"
}
```

**Now I am only concern about what exactly do I need to call using OAuthBearerClientRequest API ?**

Scope Ref URL: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&type=0

I was facing issue with OAuthBearerClientRequest API, dont know why. Raised a question here: [Could not access resource: 401 [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}] - works only in RestClient plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749260/could-not-access-resource-401-messagesession-expired-or-invalid-errorco) .

**The same I implemented using the RestTemplate it works fine.**
[image]